# how to find a tweet's favorite count number in Twitter API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I'm building a web application using the Twitter API, and was wondering if there is any way to get the the favorite count of a tweet. I searched a lot but with no luck. There must be a way cause I saw this feature in so many applications. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [unofficial API](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/01/twitter-unofficial-api-getting-tweets.html) that you can use to get tweet summary.

**To get tweet summary from the API:**

```
https://api.twitter.com/i/statuses/[tweet.id]/activity/summary.json
```

**This is the (sample) result:**

```
{
   "favoriters":[113682166],
   "favoriters_count":"1",
   "repliers":[],
   "repliers_count":"0",
   "retweeters_count":"1",
   "retweeters":[113682166]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Have you tried this link? , I tried it and it keeps telling me 'UnAuthorized'. If you know a way to get it to work please let me know

Comment: I finally got it to work with "https://api.twitter.com/i/statuses/[tweet.id]/activity/summary.json" to get the favoriters_count. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The New API V1.1 Now supports the tweet favorite's count. Here try it out

```
stdClass Object
        (
            [created_at] => Thu Apr 04 20:09:16 +0000 2013
            [id] => 319904523520983041
            [id_str] => 319904523520983041
            [text] => North Koreas perspective of the world in the next 5 years http://t.co/MxRgD00VCY
            [source] => web
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [geo] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [place] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [retweet_count] => 7
            [favorite_count] => 7
            [entities] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [hashtags] => Array
```